# Replace column with dynamic value

Tags: postgresql

There's a column in my database which has got this kind of value:

```
id|       body
-----------------------------------
1 | ... <img src=test.jpg> ... 
2 | ... <img src=test2.jpg> ... 
3 |... <img src=tests3.jpg> ....
```

Basically, after the = sign I can have anything. And I would like to change it for nothing.

I know if it was a static value I could use:

```
SELECT REPLACE(column, $$<img src=tests3.jpg>$$, ' ') FROM table
```

But I couldn't do it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

`regexp_replace()` seems ideally suited

```
SELECT REXEXP_REPLACE(column, $$<img src=[^>]*>$$, ' ','g') FROM table
```